# How to print asyncio queue?

Tags: python, debugging, queue, python-asyncio

I need to debug a queue in asyncio. How Do I know what item it contain at a particular time?
I have a queue with some data , I tried `print(list(queue))`  but has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can use the semi-private `_queue` attribute:

```
print(queue._queue)
```